# Error with google re-2 when installing apache airflow

Tags: apache-spark, installation, pip

Have had trouble the last week trying to install airflow. I get an error

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for google-re2
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
legacy-install-failure
× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> google-re2
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

I have tried things I have seen in other threads with similar issues with google-re2 package but nothing has worked. I am running Python 3.9 on macOS sonoma 14.3.1.